# What is the default root password for current Ubuntu Touch?

Tags: ubuntu-touch

I am running the latest version of `ubuntu-touch/devel`. However, I tried to get root access using the old default passwords `ubuntu` and `phablet`, but neither one is working anymore.

```
$ adb shell system-image-cli -i
current build number: 1
device name: mako
channel: ubuntu-touch/devel
alias: ubuntu-touch/vivid
last update: 2015-03-13 10:51:22
version version: 1
version ubuntu: 20141201
version device: 20141119
version custom: 20141201
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The password should be your PIN, if you have one set for the device.