# What is root password for Ubuntu Touch?

Tags: ubuntu-touch

In Terminal app, as default user `phablet` I am doing `su` and getting `Authentication failure` for everything.

As per [previous suggestions](https://askubuntu.com/q/596368/304983) I have tried `ubuntu`, `phablet`, an empty password, and the current device PIN, all without success. I entered the PIN as the device `Passphrase` instead (in `Lock security`) and tried that, without success.

Ideas?

Comment: Have you run `sudo passwd root`? You probably need to set one. Forgive me if I'm wrong.

Comment: That returns `Authentication token manipulation error` as per [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/shadow/+bug/1450880) apparently. Thanks anyway.

Comment: That's disappointing.

Comment: You can become root with  `sudo su` and the lockscreen password (I guess it's possible to log you in as root without askiing for a password if you haven't set a lockscreen code but I haven't tried it).

Comment: @SledgeHammer Works! Please add that as an answer.

Comment: i would still like to know the root password, though

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can become root by typing `sudo su` in the mobile terminal and providing the lockscreen password if required.

This is a standard procedure which also works for the regular version of Ubuntu.

Comment: for some reason, this isn't enough to edit /etc/hosts though... any clues?

Answer (score 2):

Try this: **sudo -s** That one has worked on my device.